# Python hex string

Tags: python

I have three hex strings:

```
hex1 = "e0"
hex2 = "aa"
hex3 = "b0"
string = "\\x"+hex1+"\\x"+hex2+"\\x"+hex3

print string
```

When I concatenate those three strings after appending "\x" to each of them I don't get its character representation.

I get output as `\xe0\xaa\xb0`

But when I define it in one line

```
string = "\xe0\xaa\xb0"
```

and print string I get correct output which is `ર`

What is wrong in my previous attempt?

Comment: Remove one extra \ from `\\x` and try to append.

Comment: Sorry, there was typo. Please read my comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
lst = [
    chr(int(hex1, 16)),
    chr(int(hex2, 16)),
    chr(int(hex3, 16))
]
s = ''.join(lst)  # '\xe0\xaa\xb0'
```

Your method won't work because the initial string `"\\x"` is interpreted as the string `"\x"` - and as you probably saw, creating the initial string with a single backslash (`"\x"`) is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Python comes with a lot of useful libraries, and there is a Python library for what you want, [binascii](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#module-binascii).  `binascii.unhexlify` converts a hex sequence like `'010203'` into bytes `'\x01\x02\x03'`:

```
>>> hex1 = "e0"
>>> hex2 = "aa"
>>> hex3 = "b0"
>>> s = hex1+hex2+hex3
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.unhexlify(s)
'\xe0\xaa\xb0'
```

There is even a method for what you were originally trying to do:

```
>>> hex1 = "e0"
>>> hex2 = "aa"
>>> hex3 = "b0"
>>> s= "\\x"+hex1+"\\x"+hex2+"\\x"+hex3
>>> s.decode('string-escape')
'\xe0\xaa\xb0'
```